# Is it possible to use Selenium/Python without spawning a visible window? Can I use lxml with it?

Tags: python, linux, firefox, selenium, lxml

I expect to be able to save a page and then use a `lxml.html.parse()` but I was wondering if I could do it directly off a opened page?

I'm using Ubuntu if it makes any difference.

Edit: There's a method to use xpath directly(find_element_by_xpath), so I guess I don't need lxml. But to save the page all you have to do is call the page_source method.

Comment: you can use also powershell to get hook the ie process, get document element and set values

Answer (score 2):

To answer the 'use Selenium without spawning a visible window' question, yes you can use [PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) on Ubunutu easily.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

Code is from [this blog post](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2011/06/python-headless-selenium-webdriver.html)